# Uberjar through eclipse?

Tags: java, jar

I've been researching this for a while but I have to ask: isn't it accomplishable through Eclipse by now? I've found answers regarding Maven and Ant, but I've never used either. Should my output .jar file be a runnable jar it could be done through eclipse, but it's a library that uses external jars.

So, is there something I missed or it is the Maven/Ant path for me?

Edit: regarding Jarrod answer, I'm on a tight schedule here and can't afford spare much time on this task (thanks for the tip, 'tho!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the time to learn Maven ( [maven-shade-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) ), it will pay dividends in spades!

That said, [I have done this using Ant as well.](http://www.vertigrated.com/blog/2009/11/how-to-bundle-command-line-programs-into-a-single-executable-jar-file/), and it is a much more manually intensive solution.

I use Maven 3 exclusively now and would never go back to vanilla do it all manually with Ant again.

The time it takes to Mavenize a project pays off over and over and over during the lifecycle of the project and its maintanence by other people.

The tighter the schedules the more valuable build and release automation becomes, and the less mistakes you make means less time re-doing multi-step processes that are tedious and error prone.

Comment: Well, I've paid Maven page a visit and it seems that it won't take much of my time to learn the basics. I'll go with that, thanks.

Comment: some people, given the choice between Ant and Maven, will choose Ant.  Also stuff like Gradle and Gant are definitely worth a look.  People who love the *"kitchen sinksy"* spirit may love Maven, but many do not like the kitchen sink approach (I certainly prefer to keep some control and know what's going on than having Maven produces its usual kitchen sinkyness).  The author of the following article would recommend Ant over Maven and Gradle or Gant over Ant: *http://java.dzone.com/articles/future-java-build-tools*